# Exception in Tkinter filedialog.askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to open pdf file and print file name in terminal using this code.

```
from Tkinter import * 
# Hold onto a global reference for the root window 
root = None 
filename = ''

def openFile(): 
    global filename  
    root.filename = root.filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = (("PDF File" , "*.pdf"),("All Files","*.*")))
    print root.filename

def main(): 
    global root  
    root = Tk()  # Create the root (base) window where all widgets go 
    openButton = Button(root, text="Genarate",command=openFile)
    openButton.pack()
    root.mainloop() # Start the event loop 


main()
```

but, code is not correctly working. when i press Genarate button give this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "1gui.py", line 12, in openFile
    root.filename = root.filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = (("PDF File" , "*.pdf"),("All Files","*.*")))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1902, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: filedialog
```

what is the wrong of my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tk` main window as no attribute `filedialog.askopenfilename`, you have to import `askopenfilename` from  the `tkFileDialog` module.

```
# python2
from Tkinter import * 
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
# Hold onto a global reference for the root window 
root = None 
filename = ''

def openFile(): 
    global filename  
    filename = askopenfilename( filetypes = (("PDF File" , "*.pdf"),("All Files","*.*")))
    print filename

def main(): 
    global root  
    root = Tk()  # Create the root (base) window where all widgets go 
    openButton = Button(root, text="Genarate",command=openFile)
    openButton.pack()
    root.mainloop() # Start the event loop 

main()
```

Remark: with python3 the import would be

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```